# Disable a table cell after the first click in javascript

Tags: javascript, onmouseup

I have a table cell as the following :

```
<td id=report onMouseUp='clickReport()' onKeyPress='clickReport()' >Click</td>";
```

The event function is as below :

```
function clickReport() {
document.form.submit();
}
```

On form submission, there is a back-end process going on. Until the 1st process completes(i.e., until the page reloads), I do not want the user to press the press the "Click" again, else it may affect the previous running process.
So, I thought of disabling the "Click" after the first press.

I tried using preventDefault() but it is not working.

```
function clickReport() {
document.form.submit();
document.getElementById("report").onMouseUp = function(e) 
{
 e.preventDefault();
 return false;
}
document.getElementById("report").onKeyPress = function(e) 
{
 e.preventDefault();
 return false;
}
}
```

Can someone please help!

Comment: If you are using inline event-attributes you could just set them to null: `this.onMouseUp = null;`

Comment: Use `addEventListener()` and `removeEventListener()`

Answer (score 1):

1) You might pass the *element* parameter to your event functions, so you can acces the DOM element easily. See below.

```
<td id=report onMouseUp='clickReport(this)' onKeyPress='clickReport(this)' >Click</td>";
```

2) On the first function run you might null the events, so they will not fire anymore. See below.

```
// the *element* parameter is yor <td> element here 
function clickReport(element) {
    document.form.submit();
    element.onMouseUp = null;
    element.onKeyPress= null;
}
```

3) You might use *onclick* event instead of *onmouseup* and get rid of *onkeypress*, if you only want to make it work on click.

```
<td id=report onclick='clickReport(this)'>Click</td>";

function clickReport(element) {
    document.form.submit();
    element.onclick= null;
}
```

---

Working codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MmVNMe

Comment: Setting the value as null is disabling the table cell even for the 1st click.. I am doing this after the submit(). Don't know why

Answer (score 0):

this should work.

since at first the `disableClick` is undefined  the click will fire, as soon as it fires the flag will be set to true and the click will no longer be possible.

```
<td id=report onMouseUp='!disableClick && clickReport()' 
 onKeyPress='!disableClick && clickReport()' >Click</td>"

function clickReport() {
 document.form.submit();
 window.disableClick = true;
}
```